# Composing Atlas with two different maps

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas, design

I need to create 37 different maps with their location and a detailed view with others layers active (ie. points, lines, etc). To complete this task more efficiently, I thought it would be a good idea to use Atlas feature that QGIS has, but it's been quite difficult for me since you can't (or at least I don't know) have different maps with different layers active in the map composer.

Here's an example of what I have to do 37 times (the satellite map is actually an image)

Any idea how can I do this?

[image: Example]

Comment: You can in fact have different maps with different layers active (or the same layer with different symbology)  in the map composer, you need to use map theme for this. see this for link https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422827/how-to-organize-maps-with-different-symbology/

Comment: This help?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203393/qgis-atlas-turning-on-off-raster-layers

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: @J.R Map themes solved my problem, thanks!